# Why are some PHP errors not written in the PHP log?

Tags: php, logging, error-handling

On a server I have to take care of, errors from a vhost do not go to the standard PHP error log.

In the php.ini we have

```
log = /var/log/file
```

and `phpinfo()` does not show any difference between the vhost and the whole server.

But the callback function set up by `set_error_handler()` catches errors which are not in the php log.

`error_reporting` is set to `E_ALL` once and never modified.

Could you help me to find a way to explore what's happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the errors that aren't logged [aren't supposed to be logged](http://php.net/error-reporting)? The [error reporting settings have no effect when set_error_handler is used](http://php.net/set_error_handler), hence you see more errors than are in the logfile.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at error_log, log_error and error_reporting directive in php.ini and also take a look in the httpd.conf because directives can also be added there using "php_admin_value" and others.